# What are the differences between Easy, Normal, and Hard in The Last of Us?

Tags: the-last-of-us

What are the differences between Easy, Normal, and Hard modes?

Note: please avoid spoilers!

Comment: I'm getting my ass handed at normal, that's all I know.

Comment: @Apic Not if you play stealthily. I know for a fact that enemies drop less ammo on Hard, but not much else beyond that.

Comment: why fbueckert removed the "last of us" part?, how next gamers will now i am talking about besides the tag?, imagine someone have the same question, and when typing the title, the web tries to search for a similar question, but... there is a lot!, because they are too many games with those difficulty levels!, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: He added the-last-of-us tag to your question, which classifies the game your question is referring to.

Comment: @Joe: The tag gets added to the page title, which is all that really matters for searching.

Comment: @Apic I'm glad it's not just me that suffers repeated bites to the neck.

Comment: the tag was my idea in first place..

however, imagine you have the same exact question for another game... go and try creating a new question... the system suggests you many similar question that can be related, in order to stop you to place a question that has already ansered! (see this pic: http://i.imgur.com/ZzginC8.png)

HOW can you tell if one of those question is about my game?, why people deletes the title of the game?

Also, many answers I found thanks to google search (many from stackoverflow), imagine search something like "how to parse string", w/out specifying the language!, why?

Comment: Do you people have a really good good reason to delete the game's name from question title?

Comment: @JoeCabezas: Yes, it's not necessary.  See [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/821) and [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1525)

Comment: There's no definite consensus. Some people prefer it with but many find it unnecessary. Yes, an exactly same worded question title would be rejected, but we don't need to stick the game name in every question ahead of time as a precaution. We can just add it as needed. That said, it's your question, and if you feel strongly about it and want to edit the game name right back into the question header, go for it.

Comment: Also, this is probably the most relevant meta topic about it: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6950/3062

Comment: I will write back game title, the question title without it, is ambiguous, I will stick tou Answer proposed by Grace Note here
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170056/please-show-tags-in-the-list-of-suggested-questions-that-may-already-have-your-a

Thanks Sterno!

Comment: Hey, Joe.  I wasn't trying to cause such a ruckus.  Sorry.  I've thrown the game name at the end, as that's usually a more organic title.  If you don't like it, just roll it back.

Comment: @fbueckert thanks!, I will just edit a Capital "T", because it is part of the game name (The Last Of Us), thanks again

Comment: just a comment about difficulty, be aware that switching to a lower difficulty for even one fight will mark the game as the lower difficulty (kinda makes sense, but still).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on the difficulty, you'll find more or less items during your quest for survival. The harder the difficulty, the less items you'll find. You'll still be able to find all collectibles regardless the difficulty you're playing on.

Not all items disappear on harder difficulties. Weapons, Skill Pills, Parts, Training Manuals, Comics and Artefacts can be gotten during any of your playthroughs.

The harder the difficulty, the more damage you take from enemy blows. Some enemy attacks retain their instant-kill effect on all difficulties. Enemies will also notice you considerably more quickly the harder the difficulty.

The Easy difficulty also has an additional option for 'Lock On Aiming', which makes it easier to shoot targets.

The Survivor difficulty doesn't have a Listen Mode nor Melee Prompts for in-game combat.

Source: [Walkthrough by Absolute Steve](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/652686-the-last-of-us/faqs/67205)

Comment: Also, in Easy mode you automatically have the ability to fend off clicker attacks with a shiv. (In other difficulties you have to use pills to get that ability.)

Answer (score -3):

- better AI
- more enemies
- fewer drops / resources

Sources:
 - [Review (NG)](http://www.nowgamer.com/ps3/ps3-previews/1928221/the_last_of_us_handson_what_we_love_what_we_dont_love.html)
 - [Discussion (Gamespot)](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/topic/29408755/best-difficulty-setting-for-the-last-of-us)
 - [Discussion (GameFaqs)](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/652686-the-last-of-us/66485100)

Comment: I do not believe this is a complete list, I know that Survivor mode disables X-ray vision (R2).

Comment: Better AI?, wow, i thought AI was bad in the game generally, i am in Normal Mode

Comment: I do not know the differences between easy, medium, and hard modes, but for hard v. survivor mode there is no difference in the number of enemies. There are, however, fewer drops and enemies seem to be more sensitive to sound and movement. I believe enemy damage increases as well. And the super-hearing ability is disable (as mentioned above by wr4ith).

Comment: Scyoni, I cannot find the details of your answer in the sources you cited (other than speculation from forum members).